# Specific shape in java(android)

Tags: android

How can I create a square for an android game

- with coloured sides like that in the image referred below
- that rotates left or right based on which side is tapped and
- can detect collisions with other objects and know if the colour of the object corespons with that of the colliding side?

Would it be a Square class, surface, an image, sprite, etc?

[image]

Comment: What is *collisions by corresponding colour*? Can you be more specific about the development framework?

Comment: @DirkHorsten in the image provided, each side of the square has a color. What if i were to create a ball or so that, when matched with that color on the square, it collides and increments a point or so.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont want to use some gameframework. You can calculate positions and sizes of objects in each pass of game loop. You can look in to documentation for some helpful method and classes. In example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html
Have method intersect().

But it would be the best if you would use some game framework. There are couple of lightweight game engines.

Comment: Do you have any used recommend? Can I build that square that I linked, in a game engine?

Comment: Well the most popular would be unity, its very easy to start and c# aint making your eyes explode like objective c

Comment: Any recommendations for 2D game development with Java/Android?